# Piecewise defined functions

Tags: functions

Let $f \colon [0, \pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}  \sin(x)   &\text{ if } x\text{ is irrational }\\
          \tan^2(x)  &\text{ if } x \text{ is rational.}\end{cases}$$
The number of points in the given domain at which $f(x)$ is continuous is
A. 6             B. 4            C. 2                D. 0

Please help me how to proceed with these sort of piecewise functions, related to irrational and rational numbers in the domain.

Thank you. Regards.

Comment: elcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @FakeAnalyst56 thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This combo function will be continuous at points $x$ where $\sin(x)=\tan^2(x)$.

This happens precisely when $\sin x \cos x = \sin^2 x$ or $\sin x (\cos x -1 )=0$

How many $x \in [0,\pi]$ obey that?

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to know the general resuult:
Let $I$ be an interval and $f\colon I\to\Bbb R$ be given by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&x\notin\Bbb Q\\h(x)&x\in \Bbb Q\end{cases} $$
where $g,h$ are continuous.
Then $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in I$ if and only if $g(x_0)=h(x_0)$. To see that this condition is necessary, note that we can find sequences of rational $x_n\to x_0$ and a sequence of irrational $y_n\to x$ and we need $f(x_n)=h(x_n)\to f(x_0)$ as well as $f(y_n)=g(y_n)\to f(x_0)$. It is also clear that the condition is sufficient (e.g., using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ and picking the smaller of two $\delta$'s).

So here we expect continuity precisely at this points where $\sin x=\tan^2x$, or $\cos^2x=\sin x$. You can count these by a quick glance at the graphs.
However, there is one tiny problem with this argument: $\tan^2x$ is not a continuous function on $[0,\pi$, in fact it is not defined at  a few points. But this is readily fixed: The proof abve works not only for functions $\Bbb R$, but to *any* topologicyl space. So let's consider $f$ as a function $[0,\pi]\to\Bbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$ and define $\tan^2x=+\infty$ at those gaps; then the resulting $h(x)$ is continuous and the argument above applies.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the general result?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers $f$ is continuous at points $x$ where $\sin x = \tan^2x$.

$\tan x$ is not defined at $x = \frac \pi 2$ so you have to think about that value separately.

For $x \in [0,\pi] \backslash \{\frac \pi 2\}$:

$$ \begin{align*} 
& \sin x=\tan^2x \\
\iff & \sin x \cos^2 x = \sin^2 x \\
\iff & \sin x (\cos^2 x - \sin x )=0 \\
\iff & \sin x (1 - \sin^2 x - \sin x) = 0.
\end{align*}$$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the given $f$, any interval contains both points from $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, and the limit at any $x$ must be the same when computed on $\mathbb Q$ or computed on $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. As $f_{\mathbb Q}$ and $f_{\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q}$ are two continuous functions on $\mathbb R$, their limit at $x$ are their values at $x$, and these must be equal.

Hence, you solve

$$\sin x=\tan^2x$$

which is true at

$$x=0,\arcsin(\psi),\pi-\arcsin(\psi),\pi$$ where $\psi=\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}2$.